# Nav menu not showing in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I have created a main menu but it is not possible to see in nav bar, only in apical bar (http://wpexplorer-themes.com/total)

I already used this theme pack and I never had this issue.

Thanks :

http://sam.mezoo.fr

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the position of the new menu?
Check .../wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=locations

Comment: Yes : Main and Apical, but only Apical is displayed